# Missing visual studio 2019 blazor webassembly app template

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I updated my vs 2019 16.3.10 to 16.4 and .net core 3.0 to .net core 3.1 but the blazor web assembly application template is missing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following to install the latest Blazor WebAssembly template. Run the following command:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-preview3.20168.3
```

Get the [latest version here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates/). It's free...

Comment: Just to add - to run this, in visual studio, go to Tools -> Nuget package Manager -> Package Manager Console, and paste this line in.

Comment: You can use this link to determine the latest available version number https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates

Comment: @enet I have tried your suggestion but still WebAssembly does not show up in VS2019. I m using v16.4.3 with  ,net Core 3.1.101 SDK. Any ideas?

Comment: @pantonis im having the same thing, did you figure it out

Comment: @VAAA  By defaukt ASP.NET Core 3.0 is selected. Once you select ASP.NET Core 3.1 you will see the Blazor WebAssembly App template

Comment: Not working for me with VS 2019 - Version 16.6.0 Preview 2.1

Comment: I don't know if it could help but in my VS 2019 (v 16.5.2) this tips was running well. In fact I though see the new  "Blazor WebAssembly App" and "Blazor Server App" in the first choice popup when I click on new project and filter with the word "Blazor". But in fact in this first step you just see "Blazor App", and you need to select it, click on Next, give a name of the project and click on "Create" and only at this moment you will see the choice between "Server" or "Assemblies". (cf. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio )

Comment: Thanks, fast solution for VS2019 with dotnet --version 3.1.202

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped me to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

In command line run:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.1.0-preview2.19528.8
cd C:\Users\Username\Documents\MyWebSites\BlazorWebAssySite1
dotnet new blazorwasm
```

Open VS2019, choose open project and find *BlazorWebAssySite1* folder. Done. For new projects just create a new project folder and run the last command.

Have also a look at this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bophIr--1QY .