# Visual Studio 2019 where to find WebAssembly template for .net core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, webassembly

I'm using very latest (16.4.2, dated 8th Jan 2020) Visual Studio 2019.

When I tried to create a Blazor WebAssembly solution, although the description for 'blazor app' included the words 'server or webassembly', when I got to the create page, only Server option was available and it successfully creates Core 3.1 application.

I assumed latest version would be there, so I went to the Visual Studio marketplace website and there were no Blazor extensions to be found, so looking on the internet I found running this command:

> dotnet new -i
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.1.0-preview2.19528.8

(found via [Missing visual studio 2019 blazor webassembly app template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272624/missing-visual-studio-2019-blazor-webassembly-app-template))

And it worked, I got web assembly option. However, when I look at my project created using WebAssembly it is using .net Core 2.0 and the options only go as far as 2.1. I presumed by the '3.1.0' section in the name it would be the latest.

Any idea how I get the latest template rather than random searching and use .net core 3.1?

If there is a better way, can anyone let me know how to uninstall templates as I failed to find out how.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in a CLI **or** in Tools -> Nuget package Manager -> Package Manager Console:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-preview3.20168.3
```

The NuGet package for above is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates/).

Get started with ASP.NET Core Blazor [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thanks. Couple of questions: Where do I/we find these updated versions (i.e. the magical '3.1.0-preview4.19579.2', how do I uninstall older templates, why aren't these available via the gui - I know it's for core users but a VS interface would be nice?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates/

Comment: I don't think it worked, I ran it from the nuget console and it said 'Restore completed in 2.29 sec for C:\Users\neil\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.100\scratch\restore.csproj' followed by how to use the 'new' command as if i typed something wrong. Creating new project still only shows core 2.1 and no version information for the template is made available to check.

Comment: Might just be an outdated page, but at the nuget site the link takes you to a page (https://aka.ms/dotnet-new) that only refers to .net core 1 and .net core 2?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The latest release is now an RC and can be installed with the following:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-rc1.20223.4
```

<s>The latest preview release as of April 30th can now be installed with the following:</s>

<s>dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-preview5.20216.8</s>

This requires [the latest dotnet core SDK 3.1.201](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

To check for the latest preview you can check the [ASP.NET blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/).