# Getting error "No templates matched the input template name: blazorwasm."

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to create a new .net core Blazor WebAssembly App with VS 2019 following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but so far I have had no luck.

As indicated in these docs, I've downloaded the latest preview VS 2019 Professional and typed this on a command window:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
No templates matched the input template name: blazorwasm.
```

This Blazor webAssembly feature is on preview -- it was only released very recently -- and hence understandably prone to errors, but still MS documentation normally is quite accurate, so I'm surprised this is not working as per their explanation.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668227/visual-studio-2019-where-to-find-webassembly-template-for-net-core-3-1/59668393#59668393

Comment: To get started with Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 3 install the latest .NET Core 3.1 SDK. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: Nice one @sbondo1234. That worked. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it as the answer. Many thanks!!

Comment: It is good to always check the preview release: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-3-release-now-available/

Answer (score 3):

You need .NET SDK `3.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]` to use `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`. You can view your installed version by running `dotnet --info`.

To update, eather download from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Or update vistual studio to version 16.6 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment please install

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19424.4
```

[Reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/)

Comment: 3.0.0-preview9 is a little dated, don't you think?